# Describe an algorithm which would efficiently find the minimum number of pieces

Tags: algorithms

Let 1 = L1 < L2 < . . . < Lm be positive integers and Li
is prime for i > 1. Suppose we wish to decompose a sequence of N
letters into pieces (subsequences), each of length Li
for some i, with the smallest number of pieces possible.
Describe an algorithm which would efficiently find
the minimum number of pieces. (For example, if L1 = 1, L2 = 5, and L3 = 7,
and N = 10, the optimal solution would be two pieces of length 5.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.